# Adding another 'hue' to a pairplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have plotted a pairplot in Seaborn with a hue, similar to the one shown below. I would like to add another *hue* by changing the shape of the markers based on another categorical feature. E.g., the example below was plotted using the [penguin dataset](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/penguins.csv). I would like to differentiate between data for male and female penguins by changing the marker shapes and adding another legend for each marker, whilst keeping the rest of the plot the same.

[image: Example of Seaborn pairplot]

Any ideas on how to do this are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure if this is exactly what you want, but you could create a column 'species_sex':

```
df['species_sex'] = df.sex + ' ' + df.species
```

Then plot:

```
sns.pairplot(df.sort_values('species_sex'),
                hue='species_sex',
                palette=['r', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'g', 'b'],
                markers=["o", "o", "o", 'D', 'D', 'D']);
```

[image: pairplot1]

Though I think you can see a bigger difference by just using different colors for all of the combinations:

```
sns.pairplot(df.sort_values('species_sex'), hue='species_sex')
```

[image]